# Custom Machine Image for ECS-Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to use AWS ECS Fargate. I notice that one can build their own Machine Image (AMI) to be used with ECS-EC2.

However, I do not see any documentation for how/if we can build a custom Machine Image for ECS Fargate. Is that supported? If so how can I build one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECS Fargate [uses containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/what-is-fargate.html), not virtual machines. Therefore when working with ECS, you don't use AMIs but Docker images, which are specified in the [Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task_definitions.html) with the [Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_image) parameter.